# Shallow water: running vs swimming

Tags: tactics, triathlon, multisport

Sometimes you have to switch from running in shallow water to swimming ([Iron Man with a a swimming start for example](https://youtu.be/xwYwUPVPLnM?t=7)) and since it is competition you want to be as fast as possible.

If water is knee deep then running is usually faster than swimming. On the other hand in neck-deep water swimming is obviously faster.

Are there any rules of thumb / experiments on when you should switch between swimming and running / walking to maximize your speed?

Answer (score 1):

When I was participating in triathlons with running starts, I'd run until I couldn't swing my legs over the water anymore. Then I'd transition to a "frog jump" (dive forward and down — grab and hold the bottom — push off again) until about waist deep or so. Then full-on swimming.

Comment: Description here https://www.triathlete.com/training/getting-started/open-water-swim-series-for-triathletes-the-dolphin-dive/

Comment: @pehlwaan Exactly, although I thought I invented it! ;-) BTW: I'm the co-founder of TRIATHLETE Magazine.